# Azure SQL Database Deployment "ALTER DATABASE failed because a lock could not be placed on database"

Tags: sql-server, azure-pipelines, cicd, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, database-deployment

I've gotten myself a little stuck.

We've been using Azure DevOps release pipelines to deploy DacPacs to all our internal test database environments. Some of these are Azure SQL databases, and others are SQL Server databases on real machines/VMs that are set up as deployment agents.

All the databases are the same, so we eventually deploy to them all using the same DacPac. The one with the issue is using the SQL Server database deploy task.

The process works great apart from one issue that keeps popping up.
One of the VMs hosting a SQL Server database instance keeps failing it's deployment with `ALTER DATABASE failed because a lock could not be placed on database`.

I can hop on the server, kill any processes on the SQL Server and try running the release again, and it will eventually work. The odd thing is I the processes I see are usually only my own from logging on to the server and opening SSMS. Sometimes there are existing processes, but these don't causes issues with other servers.

I'm not great at SQL server management, so honestly any steps/advice that would work with our automated processes would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why are there ALTER DATABASE commands in your deployments?  You may just be able to eliminate those, or add a ROLLBACK clause, if appropriate and available.

Comment: Doesn't the dacpac use those to make table changes? We haven't got any pre or post deploy scripts in our database project that directly alter the schema.

Comment: `ALTER DATABASE` isn't used in table creation, it's used to set options on the database itself. Most options cannot be modified while there are any active connections to the database - including the one executing `ALTER DATABASE`. Does your `sqlPackage.exe` command line include `/p:ScriptDatabaseOptions=false`?

Comment: It does not, not passing in that param at all.

Comment: You should look at the publish script and find the `ALTER DATABASE` and see what it is doing

Comment: 1. Does this issue occur in a specific DB or is it random in the affected server? 2. When your deployment fails, will you encounter the same error if you directly use sqlPackage.exe to deploy your DACPAC file locally? 3. Do you have this problem every time you deploy to a specific server, or does it happen randomly?

Comment: @ZiyangLiu-MSFT It has only been occurring on one of our VMs so far, but I think it's because that's a VM that also runs our software (it's for demoing) so the database is getting lots of locks on it regularly from the current user. I can kill those processes and after trying the deployment a few times it eventually works. I haven't tried deplyoing the DACPAC locally but if I see it again I will try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone for the comments, helped me understand the issue and solve the problem.

The solution was to add `/p:ScriptDatabaseOptions=false` to my SqlPackage.exe deployment command. (I added to additional parameters on my release pipeline).

I didn't want database settings to be changed with my DacPac deployment anyway, so it was a fine solution for me.